# How to enable support for class properties in the latest version BabelJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, ecmascript-next

Does anyone know how to enable support for properties of a class in the latest version BabelJS?

```
import React from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react';

export default class Button extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    myProp = {}; //  ERROR: /path/to/file/Button.jsx: Unexpected token (9:11)

    render(){
        return <div></div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read tag descriptions! [tag:babel] is for questions about the **Python library** with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Babel 6, you use the [`syntax-class-properties` plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-class-properties/), by installing it:

```
npm install babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties
```

and adding it to your `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": ["syntax-class-properties"]
}
```

Comment: Before ask this question, I installed and connected this plug-in. But the error remained. But then I was advised to set the preset "stage-1" and class properties were maintained.