# babel Cli inline attribute not working on babel-cli

Tags: babeljs, ecmascript-next

I'm trying to use inline attribute declaration. the code below works fine on babelJs website (Experimental option input is checked) but it doesn't work using babel-cli. expect to log inlineAttribute.

```
 /**
     * Created by Ala on 25/02/2016.
     */
    /**
     * Class Human
     */
    class Human{
        inlineAttribute = 60;
        /**
         * @constructor
         * @param name
         */
        constructor(name){
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    var Ala = new Human("Ala");
    console.log (Ala.inlineAttribute);
```

Comment: Well, you need to configure Babel correctly. http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/ . Class properties are not part of ES6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable support for class properties in the latest version BabelJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980980/how-to-enable-support-for-class-properties-in-the-latest-version-babeljs)